# Is Unknown Mode totally random? Is there a strategy to complete it?

Tags: the-basement-collection, time-fcuk

I've searched for a *The Unknown* walkthrough but the closest thing I found is [this Youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLsRI2J84FqovFx3E-cdoicfry0s4jvRZH) of only 15 levels. The problem is that each run contains 33 levels. And a good amount of them are just annoying.

The game seems to throw random levels every time (picked from where?), and I can't figure out a solution for some of them. Should I restart my run or spend my precious sleep pills to skip them?
Skipping early levels doesn't seem a good solution to me, because if I replay a skipped level the game doesn't count it as completed and I don't get the sleep pill back.

This is so frustrating.

Comment: Hiding an achievement behind user-generated levels where obnoxious and awful levels can crop up is bad game design to begin with. There should have been a report button to report obnoxious levels like ones that spawn so many blocks that it breaks the engine and makes the level impossible to beat on 9 out of 10 runs. The pool used in the unknown mode should have been curated by either the developer or a strict user rating system. I feel like the only solution now would be to organize a raid wherein people make a ton of insta-win levels and rate them as "hard", so that they appear at the end.

Comment: I went ahead and created 10 levels with literally just the exit under the player, named `"hard" i-x`, e.g. `"hard" vii`. All of them are rated 5/5 on difficulty. Hopefully they displace some of the obnoxious levels.

Comment: @BradenBest thank you for the support bro, I should give it another try in the future